# NDB Model Querying of Key Ids using an array filter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to query an NDB model using a list of provided key id strings.  The model has string ids that are assigned at creation - for example:

```
objectKey = MyModel(
    id="123456ABC",
    name="An Object"
    ).put()
```

Now I can't figure out how to query the NDB key ids with a list filter.  Normally you can do the MyModel.property.IN() to query properties:

```
names = ['An Object', 'Something else', 'etc']

# This query works
query = MyModel.query(MyModel.name.IN(names))
```

When I try to filter by a list of keys, I can't get it to work:

```
# This simple get works
object = MyModel.get_by_id("123456ABC")

ids = ["123456ABC", "CBA654321", "etc"]

# These queries DON'T work
query = MyModel.query(MyModel.id.IN(ids))
query = MyModel.query(MyModel.key.id.IN(ids))
query = MyModel.query(MyModel.key.id().IN(ids))
query = MyModel.query(MyModel._properties['id'].IN(ids))
query = MyModel.query(getattr(MyModel, 'id').IN(ids))
...
```

I always get `AttributeError: type object 'MyModel' has no attribute 'id'` errors.

I need to be able to filter by a list of IDs, rather than iterate through each ID in the list (which is sometimes long). How do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should work:

```
keys = [ndb.Key(MyModel, anid) for anid in ids]
objs = ndb.get_multi(keys)
```

Comment: Throws the following `TypeError: _parse_from_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'`

Comment: Also, this is an iteration over the list of ids, which I'm trying to avoid (this is being executed on a deferred task and has execution limits).

Comment: Its only an iteration creating the list of keys.  It is only hitting the datatstore service once with the get_multi call. This will be a much more efficient method than any query.

Comment: The id isn't a named argument in the ndb.Key constructor.  So just drop the `id=` and it will be `keys = [ndb.Key(MyModel, anid) for anid in ids]`

Comment: @TimHoffman you're right, in the `Key(kind1, id1, ...)` ctor which I'm using both the `kind` and `id` args are positional only -- thanks for spotting this, editing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use urlsafe keys If you have problems using the ids.

`keys = ndb.get_multi([ndb.Key(urlsafe=k) for k in ids])`