# GCP Datastore NDB: Filter for KindA elements keys that are NOT IN KindB documentId

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Here is my situation: I have two Datastore kind, I need to create a python query for all Data that don't are present in Kind B. In the sample those are: Data 3 and Data 4.

The constraint here is that i need to filter for elements in KindA which have a key that is different from specific KindB property.

| Kind A | Kind B |
| --- | --- |
| Data 1 | Data 1 |
| Data 2 | Data 2 |
| Data 3 |  |
| Data 4 |  |
| Data 5 | Data 5 |

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/ndb/queries), I can create a query in this way:

```
query = Account.query(Account.userid == 42)
```

I've tried this:

```
myquery = KindA.query(KindA.key.id() != KindB.documentId)
```

But it throws:
`AttributeError: 'ModelKey' object has no attribute 'id'`

I've tried following this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107978/15488129):
but it seems infeasible because the number of element in kindB is dynamic, and I can't list them all.

*Written in english my query would be: filter KindA elements keys that are NOT IN KindB documentId.*

Could you help?

Comment: Have you tried to check on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714761/ndb-model-querying-of-key-ids-using-an-array-filter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
# keys_only=True means Return only the keys which is faster
kindB_Ids = [ a.id() for a in KindB.query().fetch(keys_only=True) ]


kindA_Ids = [ a.id() for a in KindA.query().fetch(keys_only=True) ]

# This gives you rows in KindA whose ids are not in KindB
diff = [ ndb.Key(KindA, a) for a in KindA_Ids if a not in kindB_Ids]
```

Answer (score 0):

According with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714761/ndb-model-querying-of-key-ids-using-an-array-filter) quoted by @SarahRemo in the comments , here is a working solution.

```
list_of_id = []
entries = KindB.query()
for request in entries:
    list_of_id.append(request.key.id())

keys = [ndb.Key(KindA, unique_id) for unique_id in list_of_id]
objs= ndb.get_multi(keys)
```

Comment: It looks like your query will give you 1,2,5 and not 3,4. I thought you wanted 3,4